# How to get catalog product data in Magento 1.8?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I use these lines below to get the CMS page data,

```
// Get current cms page from Mage:getSingleton
$cms_id = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
$cms_title = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getTitle();
$cms_content = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getContent();
var_dump($cms_content);
```

What about if I want to get a catalog product data? I want to get the product's name for instance,

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$product_id = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getIdentifier();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
```

result,

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\mywebiste.com\app\design\frontend\mywebsite\default\template\page\html\banner.phtml
>   on line 6

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get catalog product data of particular category/product you can use below code

```
    $id = 3; // need to pass id of particular category
    $store_id = 1; // need to pass store id if you have multiple store

    $currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($store_id)->load($id);
    $collection = $currentCategory->getProductCollection();
    $collection->load();

    foreach ($collection as $product):

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());// need to pass product id if want to load particular product

    $product_id = $product->getId();
    $product_name = $product->getName();
    $product_price = $product->getPrice();
    $product_img = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage());

    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

`getIdentifier` is not a member function of `catalog/product` class
you can check

```
    $product_id = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
    var_dump(method_exists($product_id, 'getIdentifier'));
```

So its not returning a `ProductId` or loading a `Model`, in result when method `getName()` called with empty object it throws a Fatal error